# What is an appropriate end sector for expanding my partition to the end of the drive?

Tags: ubuntu, partition, gpt

Ubuntu 20.04.  I have recently cloned a 1TB storage SSD dedicated to my Nextcloud instance to a 2TB SSD.

However, the partition remains 1TB, so I want to resize it to the end of the new disk.

I attempted to use gnome's Disks utility to do this; it's in the GUI but doesn't work.

I have read 4 or 5 questions on sector math but still can't figure it out.  Here's my `fdisk -l` output for the drive in question:

```
GPT PMBR size mismatch (1953525167 != 3907029167) will be corrected by write.
The backup GPT table is not on the end of the device. This problem will be corrected by write.
Disk /dev/sda: 1.84 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 870 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 526689B4-9556-45E6-B78E-95BFC14D4DA2
```

In `fdisk` what should I set the end sector as in the new partition table?

Comment: first, you'll want to fix those first two errors ... just by writing without doing anything else in fdisk

Comment: Okay, got that taken care of.

Comment: One way to do it, take note of the details of the partition you want to "extend", delete it, re-create it with the same starting sector, the end sector should default to maximum possible, when fdisk says it's found a filesystem signature, DONT remove it - now the partition should be the new size

Comment: by the way, `gdisk -l` will also tell you the last usable sector number - which would be 34 or so less than the number of sectors - however, linux tends to prefer to align partitions on a certain number of sectors boundaries - in my case, 2048 (i.e. 1Megabyte alignment) - some other machines like 8192 sector alignment (4M)

Comment: Thanks! that worked brilliantly. `sudo fdisk -u /dev/sda` --> `d` --> `n` --> start at `2048` --> end at (accept default) --> `w` --> `q`.  do a `sudo partx /dev/sda` and then `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1` and everything is good